# Library missing from List and Libraries in SharePoint designer 2013. The library is available from All sites though

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Have a document library which was working fine till today. It has suddenly gone missing from the List and Libraries in SPD 2013. It is available through All Sites and also through a workflow associated with it.

It has a InfoPath Template which I cannot publish as it does not show me the Library name when publishing. If I say Create with the same name as earlier ...the error message says already exists( I know it does as it visible through 'Áll Sites').

How do I make it appear in the Lists and Libraries in SPD again. Tried the _vti_bin/ListData.svc does not through any errors.

Will appreciate any help with the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had clicked on the Hide from Browser option in List settings in Sharepoint designer under settings/general settings.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have a deprecated template, such as the Project Document, from a FAB40 deployment back in SP2007. When you look at the list with SP2013 UI, you may see just a dot "." in the icon area. Suspect lists would be Deliverables, Risks, Issues and Project Documents.

Within SPD, towards the bottom of the left side navigation, select "Files", then deleted the out of compliance lists and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

When we had this error is was due to a ListTemplate in use that was no longer installed on the site collection or subsite.

The easiest way I found to quickly identify the troublesome lists was to run some powershell and compare them in excel.

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb "<YOUR SITE URL>"
$web.Lists | Format-Table {$_.Title, $_.Template}
```

Copy this list into excel then run the next powershell to find the list of templates installed:

```
$web.ListTemplates | Format-Table {$_.FeatureId}
```

Copy this list into another column in excel.

Run a VLOOKUP on the two lists into a 3rd column. Any rows that come up "#N/A" that dont have a FeatureId of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000 are safe to assume that they are not installed on the site. Verify that these lists fail to load and then delete them or install the ListTemplate.

Sharepoint Designer will then show Lists and Libraries properly.

Example VLOOKUP Code: =VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,TRUE)